# Heroku is stuck

Tags: node.js, heroku, discord, discord.js, host

When running my app, the logs are next:

```
2021-08-03T17:28:40.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build started by user {my mail}
2021-08-03T17:29:09.909180+00:00 app[api]: Deploy 0b694ebd by user {my mail}
2021-08-03T17:29:09.909180+00:00 app[api]: Release v8 created by user {my mail}
2021-08-03T17:29:11.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
```

And then it is stuck on Build Succeeded.
In my code is once the bot is online/ready. Consile.log ready. But it doesn't come so my app not working.
Please help!

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes that can happen when you don't have the resources configured correctly. Make a `Procfile` file in the root directory of your project, then add this line (change `index.js` to your main file):

```
worker: node index.js
```

Then, go to https://heroku.com, log in, navigate to your project, and deploy your app. Once you do that, go to the `Resources` tab. It should show something like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q5III.png)

Click the pencil icon at the right and toggle `worker` to be on (as shown in the picture). Finally, redeploy the app, and it should be working!

Comment: Nice answer newbie!  1UP!

Comment: Thanks haha, I'm new to StackOverflow

Answer (score 0):

My main file is already index.js and i have a that file with that.
And i have setted worker as well.
My app was running fine but just randomly this happend